# Hi, I need help with this question. This quesion is based on Markov Chains. I want to answer it without using any simulation

Tags: probability, markov-process

Alinah is spending the summer at her grandparents’ farm in a small town in Iowa. The town is known for frequent changes in its weather. Each day starts off as either sunny or rainy. There’s a 50% percent chance of each. The weather can switch up to once each day, but no one knows when. If it’s a sunny day, there’s a 30% chance that the weather turns from sunny to rainy. If it’s a rainy day, there’s a 50% chance that it switches from rainy to sunny. The weather resets at the beginning of each day. Alinah decides what to do based on the weather. She starts her day at her grandparent’s farm. From the farm, she can go to the diner or to the coffee shop. If it’s sunny outside, she goes to the coffee shop. If it’s raining, she goes to the diner. From the diner, she can go back to the farm or to the park. If it’s sunny, she goes to the park. If it’s raining, she goes back to the farm. From the park, she can go to the diner or to the tennis court. If it’s sunny, she goes to the tennis court.If it’s raining, she goes to the diner. From the tennis court, she can go to the park or to the coffee shop. If it’s sunny, she goes to the park. If it’s raining, she goes to the coffee shop. From the coffee shop, she can go to the tennis court or back to the farm. If it’s sunny, she goes to the tennis court. If it’s raining, she goes back to the farm. Once she’s traveled five times, her grandparents pick her up and bring her back to the farm. Alinah spent sixty days with her grandparents. How many of those days did she visit the diner at least once? What about the park, coffee shop, and tennis court?

I am looking for the expected value i.e. probability*60. The weather can switch upto one day means that if it is sunny, it will remain sunny through out the day. Or it will transistion once to rainy and then it will remain rainy throughout the rest of the day.

Comment: The problem with probabilistic models is, that you cannot answer questions like "How many of those days...?" exactly, since there is no certainty. There is even a small change that she never visits the diner in these 60 days. So what are you looking for? The Expectation Value? The most likely number?

Comment: Also "_The weather can switch up to once each day, but no one knows when._" leaves room for interpretation.

Comment: I am looking for the expectation value i.e. probability*60. The weather can switch upto one day means that if it is sunny, it will remain sunny through out the day. Or it will transistion once to rainy and then it will remain rainy throughout the rest of the day.

Comment: Still, there are different ways to model when a weather change occurs with which probability.